# .png's not displaying

Tags: spacemacs, images

I recently uninstalled emacs 24.3 and then installed 24.5.1, because I was not able to update Spacemacs in 24.3.

Now .png images are not displaying, including the spacemacs logo that should appear on the homepage, as well as images in .org files.

Is there a library I am missing?  I am on Ubuntu.

Comment: Check that your build supports PNG's via `(image-type-available-p 'png)`

Comment: I got a `t` after running `(image(image-type-available-p 'png)`

Comment: You installed emacs via the Ubuntu package manager?  On the command line check that libpng12-0 is installed (marked "ii"): `dpkg -l 'libpng*'`.

Comment: I installed emacs using the instructions here, modified for 24.5.1:  http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/emacs-24-4-released-install-in-ubuntu-14-04/  Here are the first few lines of the output.  I'm guessing this indicates something is not right...

`Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)`

Comment: Compiling applications from source is hardly ever needed these days.  In most cases installing packages from your Linux distribution's repository is the best option.  I assume you reached the end of that article and ran `make install`?  I would recommend removing what you have compiled using `sudo make uninstall` from that source directory and then `sudo apt-get install emacs` to install emacs.  Check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu for other methods of installing Ubuntu packages.

Comment: I think I used `checkinstall` The reason I did it that way is because I wanted a newer version of emacs because some things in Spacemacs weren't working well with the older version of emacs. Unfortunately the latest in the repo is 24.3.

Comment: It looks like I have a few different versions of libpng12-0, as per `dpkg -l 'libpng*':
`ii  libpng12-0:amd64            1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14 amd64              PNG library - runtimeruntime
ii  libpng12-0:i386             1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14 i386               PNG library - runtime
ii  libpng12-dev  1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14 amd64              PNG library - development`

Maybe they are conflicting with eachother?

Comment: Don't worry; they don't conflict.  Judging from the Ubuntu repo, it looks like you are running 15.04 (vivid).  Both 15.10 (wily) and 16.04 (xenial; in alpha) contain emacs 24.5.  You can either upgrade to one of those (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade) or add one to your sources.list and install only the necessary packages for 24.5.